# Laravel elixir - don't generate map files

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

The question is - how to force Laravel Elixir not to generate map files?

At the moment if I run `gulp` I will have generated `app.css` and `app.css.map` file. I don't know what for is this `app.css.map` file but I think it's not necessary for me at the moment. Question is - how to force gulp not to generate this file?

At the moment my `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/css/app.css');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` files are called source maps. Their purpose is to *map* the contents of a concatenated, minified file to it's original files to make debugging easier.

You can disable them by changing elixirs config using `extend()` in your gulpfile

```
elixir.extend('sourcemaps', false);
```

---

Note that source maps are disabled by default when running in production.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solutions. One more question then - how to tell Elixir I'm in production environment?

Comment: Call gulp with the production flag. Like `gulp sass --production`

Answer (score 20):

This is no longer achievable via `elixir.extend()` syntax, instead the [official documentation](//laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir) now suggests to use this:

```
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting from [Elixir 3.0](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/releases/tag/3.0.0) you can put a JSON object that will override the default configuration in `elixir.json`:

```
{
    "sourcemaps": false
}
```